# Setting two subdomain on one server

Tags: proxy, vps, subdomain

I'm buing VPS server. On this server I need start Java application and PostgreSQL database. Java app is a Web service running on the port 8080 and PostgreSQL database is running on default port 5432.

***NOTE:*** I know I have placed the database and application on one server is not a good solution, but it's only a TEST environment and my boss does not want to invest in an additional VPS server.

The VPS has an IP address 1.2.3.4. This is associated with domain example.com.

**Just now:**

I have this setting in DNS:

```
example.com.        1800    IN  A   1.2.3.4
db.example.com.     1800    IN  A   1.2.3.4
ws.example.com.     1800    IN  A   1.2.3.4
```

...and this states, when I call URL:

`ws.example.com:8080/` - connect to web service

`ws.example.com:5432/` - connect to database

`db.example.com:5432/` - connect to database

`db.example.com:8080/` - connect to web service

**I need:**

`ws.example.com:8080/` - connect to web service

`ws.example.com:5432/` - get error

`db.example.com:5432/` - connect to database

`db.example.com:8080/` - get error

Is there any way, how to set this state?

Answer (score 0):

DNS is only to point to IP addresses, each service should then respond or give errors based on a named host, webservice sould give a 404 error for "db.example.com:8080" for example.

So what you want to do is configure postgres to only accept a specific host and the java webservice should be configured to respond to a specific hostname (may not be possible).

in postgres you should set the hostname with the configuration option as below:

`listen_addresses = 'db.example.com'`

Comment: And how can I set/change `listen_addresses`?? Sorry, but I'm beginner with PostgreSQL and I don't know it.

Comment: In the package you are using i'm not sure exactly where it would be in the filesystem.   maybe  `/etc/postgresql/9.3/main/pg_hba.conf`  try make that change and restart postgres.

Answer (score 0):

Dns only translate domain name into ip address. Your server at layer 2 dont know with what domain name it accessed. It can handled on layer 7 function. For example in apache do not set vhost for db.example.com. because your apache(layer 7 osi) know what from domain name it accessed, he know from his own protocol http request.